# Compare two String Arraylists complex

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparison

I have Two `ArrayList`s with String values stored in them.
The lists can be: of different size, have same values per list and different non matching strings.

Example:

```
List 1: "a","b","b","c","e","a","e","f","g";

List 2: "a","a","b","c","a","e","a","d","f","e","e","g";
```

The result I want to get is the matching values in the order of List 1 in comparison to List 2. So the result from the example would be:

Result:

```
[String] [pos L1] [pos L2]

["a"] [0] [0]

["b"] [1] [2]

["c"] [3] [3]

["e"] [4] [5]

["a"] [5] [6]

["e"] [6] [9]

["g"] [8] [11]
```

Comment: Pro-tip: when presenting a problem, always make sure you have tried to solve it, and show what you have tried. This question is likely to go on hold for the reason that there are too many ways to solve it without some initial direction/code from your side - it is thus considered Too Broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform two nested loops and start iterating in the second loop from the index you stopped in the last iteration of your inner loop:

```
public static List<String> algo(List<String> l1, List<String> l2) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

        int lastIndexFound = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < l1.size(); i++) {
            for(int j = lastIndexFound; j < l2.size(); j++) {
                String list1element = l1.get(i);
                String list2element = l2.get(j);
                if(list1element.equals(list2element)) {
                    result.add(list1element);
                    lastIndexFound = j + 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

For testing :

```
List<String> list = Lists.newArrayList("a","b","b","c","e","a","e","f","g");
List<String> list2 = Lists.newArrayList("a","a","b","c","a","e","a","d","f","e","e","g");

algo(list, list2).forEach(System.out::println);
```

This outputs :

```
a
b
c
e
a
e
g
```

Comment: You will have to deal with situation when one of the lists is empty. In this case you could return the other list or nothing - depends on you.

Comment: thanks i'll deal with that

Answer (score -1):

```
ArrayList<yourElementType> resultsArray = new Arraylist<yourElementType>()

for (yourElementType e : List1){

if(List2.contains(e)){
resultsArray.add(e)
// if you want the exact position, use list2.indexof(e)
}

}
```

Comment: I want to keep the duplicates in both arrays seperate, i eddited the main post. I hope its more clear now

Comment: It looks like my solution would return the same result array, no? Fraction of the code. Easier to understand. And no index out of array exceptions to deal with. What am I missing?